# Laravel 7 to 8 font dependency

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have upgraded from Laravel 7 to Laravel 8, but during `npm run dev`, I get the following error.

> ERROR in ./resources/assets/sass/charity/charity.scss
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
> ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> Error: Can't resolve '../../../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'
> in '/var/www/site/resources/assets/sass/charity'

This is what my package.json looks like:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "npx mix -p"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.16.2",
        "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
        "jquery": "3.2.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.7",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "vue": "^2.1.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "bootstrap-sass-datepicker": "^1.0.0",
        "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.4",
        "card": "^2.4.0",
        "cropit": "^0.5.1",
        "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.17.47",
        "jquery-maskmoney": "github:plentz/jquery-maskmoney",
        "moment": "^2.20.1",
        "quill": "^1.3.5",
        "sanitize-html": "^1.17.0",
        "sortablejs": "^1.7.0",
        "spectrum-colorpicker": "^1.8.0"
    }
}
```

If I run this, it does compile:

```
cp -R /var/www/site/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts /var/www/site/node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/
```

Can anybody explain why this is happening and if I can prevent this behaviour in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You should try updating your package.json with the following and then run `npm install`. You may have an outdated `"scripts"` section. Don't forget to run `npm run prod` afterward.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.1",
        "bootstrap-sass-datepicker": "^1.0.0",
        "bootstrap-select": "^1.13.18",
        "card": "^2.5.3",
        "cropit": "^0.5.1",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.17.49",
        "jquery": "3.6.0",
        "jquery-maskmoney": "github:plentz/jquery-maskmoney",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.25",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "postcss": "^8.3.5",
        "quill": "^1.3.7",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "sanitize-html": "^2.4.0",
        "sass": "^1.35.2",
        "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
        "sortablejs": "^1.14.0",
        "spectrum-colorpicker": "^1.8.1",
        "vue": "^2.6.14",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
    }
}
```